# How to check url parameters like frameworks do?

Tags: javascript

How make `checkUrl` function, that works similar to vue, angular, symfony, laravel? I need check domain host, and path

is there a library?

```
if (checkUrl('myShop.com/product/:id',url)) {
    console.log('matches myShop.com/product/pepsi')
}

if (checkUrl('myShop.com/product/:id/**',url)) {
    console.log('matches myShop.com/product/pepsi and myShop.com/product/pepsi/reviews/1/comments')    
}

if (checkUrl('ozon.ru/product/:id/**',url)) {
    console.log('matches ozon.ru/product/pepsi and ozon.ru/product/pepsi/reviews/1/comments')    
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

found library https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js
example usage

```
function checkUrl(pattern, url) {
    return new Route(pattern).match(url)
}

if (checkUrl('*ozon.ru/product/:id/**',location.href)) {
    console.log('matches ozon.ru/product/pepsi and ozon.ru/product/pepsi/reviews/1/comments')    
}
```